# Updated Bash via Homebrew (from 5.0.17 to 5.0.18). Now I get Error message after starting Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

Updated Bash via Homebrew (from 5.0.17 to 5.0.18). Now I get this Error message after starting Terminal:

> [Command not found: /usr/local/Cellar/bash/5.0.17/bin/bash]

> [Could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty.]

Any help would be highly apprciated. TIA

Comment: So I did a quick and very dirty fix: Just duplicated the 5.0.18 folder in /usr/local/Cellar/bash/ and renamed it 5.0.17. And yes, this works but that’s def. not the right way to fix this problem.

Comment: Found my error: I had in Terminal > Preferences > Shells open with given the path to 5.017. Just changing that to 5.0.18 fixed it for good.

Comment: Can you add this as an answer below? Also there should be an additonal directory structure in /usr/local managed by brew which always points to the most recent version (or you just use `/usr/local/bin/bash`).

Comment: @nohillside: Not sure if that is allowed.

Comment: Self-answering is allowed. It will help visitors with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that’s easy to set and easier to forget later is if you have your terminal program run a specific command rather then leave you in the default shell that `chsh` configures.

Have a look there after a brief inspection of your dot files before debugging the startup files systematically is my advice.